# Windows Phone - How to draw text over photo?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm porting an app from Android to Windows Phone 8.1. I need to get a photo from the phone's gallery, put text over the photo and then save the photo with the text back to the gallery. On Android I have been able to accomplish this, but on Windows Phone I have no idea about how to do it.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Windows Phone Runtime app or Windows Phone Silverlight app? You'll do this slightly differently for each. One common way is to combine the text and image in call and then render the combined image to a bitmap.

Comment: Windows Phone Runtime app. "One common way is to combine the text and image in call and then render the combined image to a bitmap." - Please, could you provide more details on how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to have the user enter the text, before saving the result?

Comment: Yes, I want to let the user enter whatever text they want in a TextBox, and then save the result. But I don't want the image to appear on screen

Answer (score 2):

RenderTargetBitmap provides a simple way to create a bitmap from a section of the visual tree. This means you have to show the image to the user after selection, before saving back to gallery.  If that is acceptable, then here is the XAML/Code.

This example doesn't show how to work with the gallery.

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height='10*' />
      <RowDefinition Height='10*' />
      <RowDefinition Height='2*' />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name='SourceGrid'
          Margin='10'>
      <Image x:Name='image1'
             Source='Assets/world.jpg' />
      <TextBlock Text=''
                 FontSize='20'
                 HorizontalAlignment='Center'
                 VerticalAlignment='Bottom'
                 x:Name='SourceText' />
    </Grid>
    <Image x:Name='image2'
           Source='Assets/world.jpg'
           Grid.Row='1'
           Margin='10' />
    <Button Content='Add Text'
            Grid.Row='2'
            HorizontalAlignment='Center'
            Click='Button_Click' />

  </Grid>
```

**Code**

```
 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      var tempBmp = new RenderTargetBitmap();

      SourceText.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("D");
      await tempBmp.RenderAsync(SourceGrid);
      SourceText.Text = string.Empty;
      image2.Source = tempBmp;

    }
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! But I don't want to show the picture to the user